# Convert AWS CLI command into Python AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli

I'm using an AWS CLI command to extract results for reporting and I must create a lambda that does the same job but is facing many problems with syntax errors

The current AWS CLI command:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`platform`]|[0].Value, Tags[?Key==`resource-version`]|[0].Value]| sort_by(@, &[0])' \
    --output table \
    --filter Name=tag:platform,Values=aip,mmt,pame --profile prod | uniq
```

Could you help me to make the same code with python please?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the AWS Python SDK (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html).
If you scroll through the documentation, or crtl+f for `describe instances` you will eventually find this resource that might help you.
If you already tried running the same command with Python, and you did get errors, please post the python code and the errors, otherwise no one will be able to hlep you.

Comment: Can you please explain, in words, what is the output you are seeking? It seems to be that you want the `platform` and `resource-version` tags for instances where the `platform` has a value that is one of `aip`, `mmt` and `pame`. Is that correct? Don't you want the Instance ID as well?

Comment: No i obtained this result : Deployed versions are :
mmt 1.104.12
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.104.12
aip 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.104.12
aip 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
aip 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

Now i can print this result :

Deployed versions are :

`mmt 1.104.12
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.104.12
aip 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.104.15
mmt 1.104.12
aip 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
aip 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT
mmt 1.112.0-SNAPSHOT`

Using this cide `import boto3

def instance_list(tagkey, tagvalue):
    # When passed a tag key, tag value this will return a list of InstanceIds that were found.

```
ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2client.describe_instances(
     Filters=[
      {'Name':'tag:platform', 'Values':["mmt","pame","aip"]}
]
)
name = []
instancelist= []
print ("Deployed versions are :")
for reservation in (response["Reservations"]):
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
       for tag in instance['Tags']:
           if tag['Key'] == 'platform':
               name.append(tag["Value"])
           if tag['Key'] == 'resource-version':
               instancelist.append(tag["Value"])
a  = [name + instancelist]
for x, y in zip(name, instancelist):
    print (x, y)
```

`

Am trying to delete duplicated line and send result by mail or slack; Any help please ?